# While INSERT got error PLS-00904: stud.col3 is invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

In my stored procedure I want if the value of **col1** & **col2** match with employee then insert the unique record of the employee. If not found then match the value of **col1**, **col2** & **col3** with ***employee*** match then insert the value. If also not found while match all these column then insert the record by using another column.

Also one more thing that I want find list of values like **emp_id** by passing the another column value and if a single record can not **match** then make **emp_id** as **NULL**.

Also I want to insert one record at a time after match with **txt** along with others table having data like **emp**.

```
create or replace procedure sp_ex
as
    cursor c1 is select * from txt%rowtype;
    v_col1 tbl1.col1%type;
    type record is table of txt%rowtype;  --Staging table
    v_rc record := record();
begin
    open c1;
    loop 
        fetch c1 bulk collect into v_rc limit 1000;

        loop
            for i in 1..v_rc.count loop
                select col1 into v_col1 from tbl1
                where  exists (select col1 from tbl1 where tbl1.col1 = emp.col1);

                insert 
                    when txt.col1 = emp.col1 and txt.col2 = stud.col2 then
                         into main_table(columns) values(v_rc(i).col1, ...)

                    when txt.col1 = emp.col1 and txt.col2 = stud.col2 and txt.col3 = stud.col3 then 
                         into main_table(columns) values(v_rc(i).col1, ...)

                    else 
                         insert into main_table(columns) values(v_rc(i).col1, ...)
                         select * from txt;
                end loop;
                exit when v_rc.count < limit;

        end loop;
        close c1;
end sp_ex;
```

While **emp**, **stud** are the different tables where i have to match with **txt**.
In that Stored Proc I want to load data from **txt** into **main_table** in batch processing mode. The data would be match one by one record then after if matching condition match then load into the main table. How can i create the stored proc so that the Data will load by above logic one by one in batch processing. Could you please help me to share your idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax seems to be rather mixed up.

[Multi-table insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) is like this:

```
insert all  -- alternatively, "insert first"
    when dummy = 'X' then
        into demo (id) values (1)
    when dummy = 'Y' then
        into demo (id) values (2)
    else
        into demo (id) values (3)
select * from dual;
```

Or perhaps you wanted a [PL/SQL `case` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CASE-statement.html):

```
case
    when dummy = 'X' then
        insert into demo (id) values (1);
    when dummy = 'Y' then
        insert into demo (id) values (2);
    else
        insert into demo (id) values (3);
end case;
```

Instead there seems to be a mixture of the two.

Also there is a missing `end loop`, and an implicit cursor (`select col1 from tbl1`) with no `into` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already did but i want to know that for each record this will txt data will match with some another table then after load it into the main table

Comment: how to match the condition first as mention above from the another table then after load it into the main table. because you didn't mention the MATCH case here. could you please let me know because i am facing some confusion here.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand that part of your question. Probably you need `insert ... select ... from ... where ...` but I would need to see some table definitions and join conditions to comment in any more detail.

Comment: in this SP we have to apply 2 different logic. 1st logic is `select ... from .... where` and the another logic we have to apply is `insert` after matching the record as above condition. What would be the logic have to apply.could you please let me know.

Comment: Well, the *'insert after matching the record as above condition'* could be  `insert ... select ... from ... where ...` but as I said I would need [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) added to the question.

Comment: when i use `insert ... select ... from ... where ...` then i found an error `Column ambiguously defined` when i insert data into main table having same column

Comment: before `exit when v_rc.count < limit;` can we use **stud** and **emp** table using JOIN condition.